# Prove that a mapping from a separable space to the Hilbert cube is a homeomorphism

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(M, \rho)$ is separable, and that $\rho(x,y)\leq 1$ for all x and y in M. Let $x_n$ be a countable dense set of M. Define the Hilbert cube $H^{\infty}$ as the collection of all real sequences $y_n$ were $\lvert y_n \rvert \leq 1$ for all n. Define a metric $d$ on this space by $d(x, y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert$. Then define $f : M \rightarrow H^{\infty}$ by $f(x) = \rho(x, x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$. The goal is to show $f$ is a homeomorphism onto its image. I have shown it's 1-1 and continuous, but the book I'm going through then says that I need to show that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $\rho(x,y) < \epsilon$ whenever $d(f(x), f(y)) < \delta$, and I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $f(x^{j}) \to f(x)$ in the range of $f$ then $\rho (x^{j},x_n) \to \rho (x,x_n)$ for each $n$ because convergence in $H^{\infty}$ implies convergence of each coordinate.  Now $\rho (x^{j},x) \leq \rho (x^{j},x_n)+\rho (x_n,x)$. Given $\epsilon >0$ choose $n$ such that the second term is less than $\epsilon$ and the let $j \to \infty$. Thus $f(x^{j}) \to f(x)$  implies $x^{j} \to x$ which means $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Comment: Did you mean to choose n such that the second term is less than half of epsilon and then let j go to infinity?

Comment: @aphyd yes, there was a typo.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your answer!